# Вызов C++ функций из PyPy

Tags: python, pypy, c++

Как использовать Foreign Function Interface для вызова функций, написанных (или даже уже скомпилированных) на С++ из PyPy?

Насколько мне известно, PyPy имеет FFI, но подробной документации о том, как его непосредственно использовать, нет.

Comment: связанный вопрос: [Динамическая библиотека C++ в Python](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/731789/23044)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Чтобы вызвать С функции, можно использовать как [ctypes (из стандартной библиотеки)](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ctypes.html), так и [cffi модуль, рекомендованный для pypy](https://cffi.readthedocs.org/).

Чтобы С++ функции вызывать, можно просто `extern "C" {..}` обёртки добавить.

**Обновление**

Если приведённой по ссылками документации недостаточно, то предпочтительно более специфичный вопрос по конкретной задаче задать.

Comment: Вроде, достаточно, но я как-то про классы забыл, которые в С++ библиотеках содержатся.

Comment: @Montreal: Если имеется ввиду как С++ класс превратить в Python класс, то это уже не FFI территория, здесь нужны инструменты, которые умеют создавать расширения для CPython, написанные на C++, многие из этих инструментов такие как  SWIG, Boost.Python, Cython могут не работать с Pypy. Быстрый поиск по гуглу возвращает [cppyy модуль для pypy](http://doc.pypy.org/en/release-2.4.x/cppyy.html) (не могу сказать насколько он работоспособен)