# Динамическая библиотека C++ в Python

Tags: c++, python, dll, ctypes

Тест задачи:

> Создать динамическую библиотеку на одном языке (С++) и
>   использовать её в другом (Python). На C++ написать динамическую
>   библиотеку, которая содержит в себе вычислители нескольких
>   математических функций (функции принимают коэффициенты в качестве
>   параметров и возвращают массив точек с некоторым шагом); на
>   Python, используя pylib, написать программу, которая строит
>   графики функций, вычисленных в динамической библиотеке.

Собственно не знаю как сделать импорт библиотеке из C++ в Python, помогите пожалуйста с реализацией.

Comment: У вас проблема только с импортом? [Импортирование динамической библиотеки](https://docs.python.org/3/extending/extending.html#a-simple-example) аналогично обычному модулю.

Comment: Модуль ctypes еще можно использовать. В чем проблема у вас - непонятно.

Comment: `boost::python` спасет мир

Answer (score 2):

Чтобы напрямую использовать dll из Питона, существуют [`ctypes`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ctypes.html), `cffi` модули.

К примеру, чтобы вызвать `printf()` функцию из стандартной Си библиотеки напрямую:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python
import ctypes
from ctypes.util import find_library

try:
    libc = ctypes.cdll.msvcrt  # Windows, load msvcrt.dll
except OSError:
    libc = ctypes.cdll.LoadLibrary(find_library('c'))  # load libc.so.6

n = libc.printf(b"abc ")
libc.printf(b"%d\n", n)
```

Вот более сложный [пример вызова `clock_gettime()` C функции из `<time.h>` (`-lrt`)](https://gist.github.com/zed/5073409).

Чтобы вызвать C++ функцию, её следует экспортировать как `extern "C"`:

```py
extern "C" int f(int n, double* points);
```

В более сложных случаях [можно Cython использовать](http://cython.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/userguide/wrapping_CPlusPlus.html), чтобы обернуть C++ библиотеку, предоставляя идиоматический Питон интерфейс остальному коду. Существует [множество других библиотек, которые помогают связывать Python и С/C++ код в разных ситуациях.](https://wiki.python.org/moin/IntegratingPythonWithOtherLanguages#C.2FC.2B-.2B-)