# Работа с Си и Python: как можно воспользоваться библиотекой написанной на си в питоне, можно ли вообще это сделать?

Tags: python, c, dll, com, нагрузочное-тестирование

Доброго времени суток!
Имеется плата для нагрузочного тестирования, подключаемая к ПК через COM порт. Имеется библиотека, написанная на си для упаковывания отправляемых данных в определенный вид и с кастомным подсчетом CRC. Вопрос в следующем - требуется создать скрипт на питоне для нагрузочного тестирования, я не понимаю, как можно воспользоваться библиотекой написанной на си в питоне, можно ли вообще это сделать? Предыдущие тестировщики работали в среде созданной на Ruby и писали на нем, сейчас же задача иная. Я новичок в плане питона, поэтому ссылки на почитать и советы приветствуются.
Вот код библиотеки

```
unsigned char* DataToSend(unsigned char address, unsigned char rdnum, 
unsigned int cardnum, unsigned char pindigit, unsigned char state, unsigned 
short action, unsigned char ccounter)
{
unsigned char size;
unsigned short flag, crc_15;
unsigned short crc = 0xFFFF;
int i,k;
unsigned char data;

const unsigned short msk_11_4 = 0x0810;
const unsigned short msk_data = 0x80;
const unsigned short msk_15 = 0x8000;

if(action != 4) size = 14;
else size = 17;

unsigned char *buf = NULL;
buf = (unsigned char*)malloc(size);

if(size == 14)
{
    buf[7] = address;
    buf[8] = 0x00;
    buf[9] = 0xDA;
    buf[10] = 0x03;
    buf[11] = action;
    buf[12] = rdnum;
    if(action != 1) buf[13] = state;
    else buf[13] = pindigit;

    for(k = 7; k < size; k++)
    {
        data = buf[k];
        for (i = 0; i <= 7; data <<= 1,i++)
        {
            crc_15 = crc & msk_15;
            if (data & msk_data)
                flag = crc_15 == msk_15? 0: msk_15;
            else
                flag  = crc_15;
            if (flag)
                crc = ((msk_11_4 ^ crc) << 1) | 1;
            else
                crc <<= 1;
        }
    }

    buf[5] = (unsigned char)(crc >> 8);
    buf[6] = (unsigned char)(crc & 0x00FF);
    buf[4] = 0x07;
    buf[3] = 0x00;
    buf[2] = ccounter;

    for(k = 2; k < 7; k++)
    {
        data = buf[k];
        for (i = 0; i <= 7; data <<= 1,i++)
        {
            crc_15 = crc & msk_15;
            if (data & msk_data)
                flag = crc_15 == msk_15? 0: msk_15;
            else
                flag  = crc_15;
            if (flag)
                crc = ((msk_11_4 ^ crc) << 1) | 1;
            else
                crc <<= 1;
        }
    }

    buf[0] = (unsigned char)(crc >> 8);
    buf[1] = (unsigned char)(crc & 0xFFFF);
}
else
{
    buf[7] = address;
    buf[8] = 0x00;
    buf[9] = 0xDA;
    buf[10] = 0x06;
    buf[11] = 0x04;
    buf[12] = rdnum;
    buf[13] = 0x00;
    buf[14] = (unsigned char)(cardnum >> 16);
    buf[15] = (unsigned char)(cardnum >> 8);
    buf[16] = (unsigned char)(cardnum & 0x00FF);

    for(k = 7; k < size; k++)
    {
        data = buf[k];
        for (i = 0; i <= 7; data <<= 1,i++)
        {
            crc_15 = crc & msk_15;
            if (data & msk_data)
                flag = crc_15 == msk_15? 0: msk_15;
            else
                flag  = crc_15;
            if (flag)
                crc = ((msk_11_4 ^ crc) << 1) | 1;
            else
                crc <<= 1;
        }
    }

    buf[5] = (unsigned char)(crc >> 8);
    buf[6] = (unsigned char)(crc & 0x00FF);
    buf[4] = 0x0A;
    buf[3] = 0x00;
    buf[2] = ccounter;

    for(k = 2; k < 7; k++)
    {
        data = buf[k];
        for (i = 0; i <= 7; data <<= 1,i++)
        {
            crc_15 = crc & msk_15;
            if (data & msk_data)
                flag = crc_15 == msk_15? 0: msk_15;
            else
                flag  = crc_15;
            if (flag)
                crc = ((msk_11_4 ^ crc) << 1) | 1;
            else
                crc <<= 1;
        }
    }

    buf[0] = (unsigned char)(crc >> 8);
    buf[1] = (unsigned char)(crc & 0xFFFF);
}

return buf;
}
//--------------------------------------------------------------------------
--------------------------------------------------


void MemoryFree(unsigned char *pbuf)
{
realloc(pbuf, 0);
}
//--------------------------------------------------------------------------
--------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: связанный вопрос https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/731789/23044

Comment: Модуль ctypes вполне подходит для вызова сишного кода из Питона

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Совет как новичку - ищите книги "контрибуторов" языка. вот например:
Бизли Д. - Python. Подробный справочник (4-е изд.) - 2010
там есть ответ на ваш вопрос на 734 и 759-765 страницах, используя модуль `ctypes`

Ну - и документация в помощь: https://docs.python.org/3/library/ctypes.html?highlight=ctypes#module-ctypes

Чтобы писать на Python, а не использовать синтаксис Python для кодирования в духе, скажем, языка С, можно полистать книгу Лучано Рамальо: Python. к вершинам мастерства. Где найти - думаю справитесь )