# Использование статических библиотек (C++) в С# и Python

Tags: c#, c++, python, lib

Можете ли вы пояснить мне, возможно ли использование статических библиотек, написанных на C++, в приложениях на C# и Python. Во время компиляции статической библиотеки создаются объектные файлы, содержащие машинный код и тут первая проблема: C# компилируется в байт-код и в программу на нём, вероятно, не удастся встроить такой файл. А с Python ещё интереснее - он интерпретируемый язык.

Мой вопрос: возможно ли использование статических библиотек, написанных на C++, в приложениях на C#, Python. Если да, то каким образом они подключаются и каким образом из программы на C#, Python можно обратиться к функциям библиотеки? + как будет вести себя C#, Python при этом (будет ли надобность в lib файле после компиляции?) Буду благодарен, если Вы найдёте литературу по этому вопросу.

Comment: Касаемо C#, именно статическую библиотеку использовать не получится, вот ответ https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21005412/pinvoking-functions-from-a-static-c-library

Comment: Невозможно. Объектные файлы содержат какое-то промежуточное представление скомпилированного кода (не факт, что там вообще присутствует машинный код). Соответственно исполнять их нельзя, а компилятора с поддержкой компоновки сразу с++, c# и python вроде как еще в природе нет.

Comment: Вот этой фразы оттуда должно быть достаточно "If you want to call a lib, you must first create a DLL (using C++). Then you can PInvoke that DLL. "

Comment: Какой конечный результат? Один исполняемый файл, содержащий все компоненты? без обращения к динамическим библиотекам или достаточно, чтобы только указанные библиотеки внутри жили? `Modules/Setup` позволяет некоторые модули прямо в python executable встроить.

Comment: в обратную сторону: [вызов Питон-кода из C++](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/726439/23044)

Comment: related: [Compile the Python interpreter statically?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1150373/4279)

Answer (score 0):

Всем известный Лутц помимо всем известной книги "Изучаем Python" написал еще и двухтомник "Программирование на Python". В этой книге, во втором томе, есть глава 20, которая так и называется "Интеграция с С++".  Возможно, там вы найдете ответы на многие свои вопросы.
Еще кое что можно почерпнуть вот тут:
https://ideafix.name/wp-content/uploads/2012/09/Python-13.pdf

В документации по Python также есть соответствующий, весьма подробный (и длинный :-))  раздел:
https://docs.python.org/3.6/extending/extending.html

Comment: обратите внимание на слово "статических" в заголовке

Comment: для динамического случая ответ: [Динамическая библиотека C++ в Python](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/731789/23044)